# Crear vista detallada de un objecto de un modelo con llaves foráneas

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

Estoy aprendiendo Django y estoy haciendo un aplicación para registro de ingreso a posgrado.

Deseo poder visualizar el contenido de un registro que se mande en la URL, por ejemplo: `localhost/administracion/detalle/1`

Tengo las siguientes tablas en `project/apps/solicitud/models.py`:

```
class Candidato(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{} {}'.format(self.nombre, self.apellidos)


class InfoPersonal(models.Model):
    # relación de una mascota por persona, si se borra persona, se borra la mascota
    candidato = models.ForeignKey(Candidato, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=SEXO_CHOICES)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    curp = models.CharField(max_length=18, unique=True)

    pais_origen = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="México")
    lugar_nacimiento = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    domicilio = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    codigo_postal = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}'.format(self.curp)


class InfoAcademica(models.Model):
    persona = models.ForeignKey(Candidato, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    escuela_procedencia = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    programa_solicitado = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PROGRAMA_SOLICITADO_CHOICES, default=MAS_ADMIN)
    titulado = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ESTADO_TITULACION_CHOICES, default=YA_TITULADO)
    titulacion_creditos = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices= TITULACION_CREDITOS_CHOICES, default=NO)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}'.format(self.programa_solicitado)


class Solicitud(models.Model):
    candidato = models.ForeignKey(Candidato, null=True, blank=True)
    academica = models.ForeignKey(InfoAcademica, null=False, blank=False)
    Personal = models.ForeignKey(InfoPersonal, null=False, blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Solicitud id: {}'.format(self.id)
```

Y quiero crear una vista detalle donde pueda ver todos los campos del candidato
la cual está en `project/apps/administracion/views.py`:

```
class DetalleCandidato(DetailView):
    model = Solicitud
    template_name = 'administracion/detalle_candidato.html'
```

Aquí muestro el HTML de la clase DetalleCandidato, donde quiero ver todos los datos de las tablas: `templates/administracion/detalleCandidato.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {{ solicitud.candidato.nombre }}
    {{ solicitud.candidato.apellidos }}
    {{ solicitud.candidato.email }}

    {{ solicitud.Personal.sexo }}
    {{ solicitud.Personal.fecha_nacimiento }}
    {{ solicitud.Personal.curp }}
    {{ solicitud.Personal.pais_origen }}
    {{ solicitud.Personal.lugar_nacimiento }}
    {{ solicitud.Personal.domicilio }}
    {{ solicitud.Personal.telefono }}
    {{ solicitud.Personal.telefono }}

    {{ solicitud.academica.escuela_procedencia}}
    {{ solicitud.academica.programa_solicitado }}
    {{ solicitud.acemica.titulado }}
    {{ solicitud.academica.titulacion_creditos }}

{% endblock content %}
```

Esta son mis URLs `project/apps/administracion/urls.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import views

app_name = 'administracion'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', login_required(views.ListarSolicitudes.as_view()), name='lista_solicitud'),
    url(r'detalle/(?P<pk>\d+)$', login_required(views.DetalleCandidato.as_view()), name='detalle_solicitud'),
]
```

No puedo ingresar a la URL para comprobar si mi HTML puede renderizar los campos que estoy solicitando.

Comment: Pero quieres mostrar el detalle solo del candidato o todo el detalle de la solicitud que es la que contiene las foraneas ?

Comment: Quiero mostrar todo el detalle, la solicitud es más que nada la forma de unir los modelos y ver que no puedan hacer otra solicitud, acabo de revisar que debo confirmar los datos de la Clase solicitud, por que si no lo hago, no se crea y crea error en la URL, esto lo hice  con la página del admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, hay varios detalles a corregir:

-La vista de candidato que tienes no es optima

-El nombrado de urls es maa complejo de lo que deberia.

-Personal y academica no existen, los modelos se llaman InfoPersonal e InfoAcademica respectivamente.

Para lograr lo que necesitas:

**Views.py**

class VerDetalle(BaseView):

```
template = 'committee/minute_management.html'

def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    solicitud = get_object_or_404(Solicitud, pk = kwargs['id_solicitud'])

    return render(request, self.template, {'solicitud': solicitud })
```

**Añadir a patterns en Urls.py**

```
url(r'^solicitud/detalle/(?P<id_solicitud>\d+)/$', views.VerDetalle.as_view(), name = "ver_detalle"),
```

De esta forma, en tu template puedes llamar todo los datos:

**template.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {{ solicitud.candidato.nombre }}
    {{ solicitud.candidato.apellidos }}
    {{ solicitud.candidato.email }}

    {{ solicitud.infopersonal.sexo }}
    {{ solicitud.infopersonal.fecha_nacimiento }}
    {{ solicitud.infopersonal.curp }}
    {{ solicitud.infopersonal.pais_origen }}
    {{ solicitud.infopersonal.lugar_nacimiento }}
    {{ solicitud.infopersonal.domicilio }}
    {{ solicitud.infopersonal.telefono }}
    {{ solicitud.infopersonal.telefono }}

    {{ solicitud.infoacademica.escuela_procedencia}}
    {{ solicitud.infoacademica.programa_solicitado }}
    {{ solicitud.infoacademica.titulado }}
    {{ solicitud.infoacademica.titulacion_creditos }}

{% endblock content %}
```

Es importante resaltar que deben existir datos para que funcione por supuesto, y que debes tener un botón quer llame a la url enviando el parametro respectivo (id_solicitud)

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, me acabo de dar cuenta de que no puedo enlazar los modelos InfoPersonal e InfoAcademica a Solicitud automáticamente, lo hice por el admin, pero al querer hacerlo por un formulario, me daba error de instancia, creo que con esto podré solucionar ese problema

Comment: Con gusto hombre, para eso estamos !